# Rails 4/ActiveAdmin: Add link to list all objects from has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I am using a cached_counter to keep track of all comments for a user.
My model relationship look like this:

```
class User  < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :comments
end 

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
 comment belongs to user, counter_cache: true
end
```

and the user table holds the counting variable.
In Activeadmin i have a column `:comments_count` which shows the  amount of comments for each user.
So far so good.
Now i would like to modify it a bit. I would like to add  a link  which directs to a page where all comments  are listed. How can do this?

I am checking the AA [live demo][1] since they do something similar there.

My idea was to create a partial view and link_to it. But i m struggling implementing it and i dont know if this is *best practise* anyways.
I have this query

```
 Comments.where(:User_id => :id)
```

but how to i embed it into a column?

Thank for any advice .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle this situation by linking to the admin index page for `Comment` with a filter pre-set for the given `user_id`. This requires drastically less code then a custom page, and gives you direct access to scopes, filters, etc.

Here's how:

```
index do
  # make sure you set sortable, so you can click to sort!
  column :comments_count, sortable: 'users.comments_count' do |user|
    link_to user.comments_count,
            admin_comments_path(q: { user_id_eq: user.id })
  end
end
```

**Edit:**

The ActiveAdmin index controller uses [Ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) to handle searching and filtering. Ransack accepts query options in the form of a hash that obeys a sort-of DSL (the `user_id_eq` bit above is an example). Now if you open any ActiveAdmin index route and start playing around with filters, you'll see those parameters tacked on to the end of the url using the same convention. The `?q=...` part gets passed directly to Ransack in the index controller, and that's how your models get filtered. Our code above simply links to the index page with the `id` filter pre-set. You can add other filters, sort orders, or even scopes as well.

Comment: Perfect!!Thanks so much that works exactly the way is imagined it :) I can follow your code except the admin customer path parameter set. Could you explain this block a bit? Cheers